# Python: thread in PyQt, emit method to get the data

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I try to get the value of `Count_total_value` in my user interface when I call `Continusread` method, (it should  be `"toto"` according to what I want to do) but it is always the default value `"azerty"` which is displayed. Please can you tell me where I am wrong?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
import threading
from ctypes import *
import ctypes
#import Converted Python UI File
from test_error_rx import Ui_MainWindow

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    Count_total_valuechanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.Count_total_value = 'Azerty'

    def run(self):
    ##do things to calculate Count_total_value
        Count_total_value='toto'
        self.Count_total_valuechanged.emit((self.Count_total_value))
        time.sleep(0.1)


class Main( QtGui.QMainWindow,QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Connect the Buttons
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.Continusread,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.Continusread)

        self.__thread = MyThread(self)
        self.__thread.Count_total_valuechanged.connect(self.ui.Count_total.setText)

    def Continusread(self):
       self.__thread.start()

    def main():
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Main()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `run()` method of your thread class `MyThread` you set `Count_total_value='toto'` when it should be `self.Count_total_value='toto'`.

Note that when posting on stackoverflow you should:

1. post a minimilistic **working** example (you haven't included your UI in the above code so no-one can run your script)
2. Check the posted code has the correct indentation and fix any mistakes (your posted code is a mess of incorrect indentation)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot it works! and sorry for your 2 remarks that I understand very well. Next time I will do my best to correct these 2 points. Thanks